# kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError) when using fastlane

Tags: ruby

When I execute this command in macOS 10.15:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

shows this error:

```
~/source/cruise-open/android on  android! ⌚ 22:20:24
$ bundle exec fastlane beta                                                                                                                                    ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    11: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    10: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `activate_bin_path'
     8: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `synchronize'
     7: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:306:in `block in activate_bin_path'
     6: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
     5: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:435:in `resolve_current'
     4: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:435:in `new'
     3: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/resolver/set.rb:24:in `initialize'
     2: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require'
     1: from /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `synchronize': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)
(base)
```

what shoud I do to fix this problem? This is my Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    crashlytics
  
    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY'],
        user_key: ENV['PGY_USER_KEY']
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Where are your locks? If it’s in your code, show it. If it’s in the gem, report it upstream.

Comment: not in my code, in the gem @ToddA.Jacobs